# suggested code style for chip register read/write?

Tags: c++, c

I am writing code to access some chips on my PCB board, for example, there is a chip with two registers defined as below :

[register#1 content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cpaR8.png)

[register#2 content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CG4FW.png)

Each register has different address and content value, and address and value are both a 16-bits word.
I have defined structs for each registers for example :

```
typedef struct _CHIP01_REG01
{
    union
    {
        struct
        {
            unsigned short software_reset : 1;  //bit[0]
            unsigned short reg_read_en : 1;     //bit[1]
            unsigned short add_offset : 1;      //bit[2]
            unsigned short reserved : 13;       //bit[15:3]
        } value_bit;
        unsigned short value_all;
    } value;

    unsigned short const address = 0x00;

} CHIP01_REG01;

typedef struct _CHIP01_REG02
{
    union
    {
        struct
        {
            unsigned short global_pdn : 1;      //bit[0]
            unsigned short reserved1 : 4;       //bit[4:1]
            unsigned short dis_lvds : 1;        //bit[5]
            unsigned short reserved2 : 8;       //bit[13:6]
            unsigned short lvds_rate_2x : 1;    //bit[14]
            unsigned short reserved3 : 1;       //bit[15]
        } value_bit;
        unsigned short value_all;
    } value;

    unsigned short const address = 0x01;

} CHIP01_REG02;
```

then define a struct to hold all the registers of a chip,

```
typedef struct
{
    CHIP01_REG01        chip01_reg01;
    CHIP01_REG02        chip01_reg02;
} CHIP01_REGS;
```

then I would like to write functions to read/write the registers, for now, my function is as below,

```
bool RegisterWrite_1
(
    unsigned short  regAddress,
    unsigned short regVal
)
{
    // write "regVal" into address "regAddress"
    return true;
}
```

so setting register content and write a register is like this,

```
chip01_regs.chip01_reg01.value.value_bit.software_reset = 0;
chip01_regs.chip01_reg01.value.value_bit.add_offset = 1;
RegisterWrite_1( chip01_regs.chip01_reg01.address, chip01_regs.chip01_reg01.value.value_all );
```

the above code is lengthy and error-prone, especially when many registers are required to be set to make the chip function normally.

I would like to know if there is a way to define a function "RegisterWrite_2()", where function input is a pointer to a register and register address/value is extracted inside the function

```
bool RegisterWrite_2
(
    REG_PTR *reg_ptr
)
{
    unsigned short regAddress = *reg_ptr.address;
    unsigned short regVal = *reg_ptr.value;
    // write "regVal" into address "regAddress"
    return true;
}
```

If the above is possible, code to write a register could be done in a much clear way like the third line as below,

```
chip01_regs.chip01_reg01.value.value_bit.software_reset = 0;
chip01_regs.chip01_reg01.value.value_bit.add_offset = 1;
RegisterWrite_2( &chip01_regs.chip01_reg01 );
```

the problem is, input type "REG_PTR" in RegisterWrite_2() is not a fixed type, each register belongs to different types (CHIP01_REG01, CHIP01_REG02), so I do not know how to assign "REG_PTR". However, each register occupies the same size of memory (16 bits value and 16 bits address), so I believe there is some way to deal with this condition.

hope I had described my question clearly enough, and since I am a newbie to C++ hope this is not a stupid question, looking forward to your reply, thanks in advance !

Comment: `typedef struct` is a C thing and doesn't make much sense in C++. Other than that I don't understand what you are asking

Comment: First of all use of bit fields is dangerous (when you use then for communication), for example `on some platforms, bit fields are packed left-to-right, on others right-to-left`. The main problem is that problem is not clear. I understand that you want to make code cleaner. Problem is that desired functionality is quite vague.

Comment: @MarekR I really wish it was standardized, as when someone says "bit 15" in a documentation sheet I know exactly what they're talking about. I just declare it as an unsigned type and use hex values when writing to it to communicate to the reader that these are bit flags.

Comment: @puppydrum64 this is caused by hardware. C++ code runs not only on x86 or ARM. THat is why C++ has so many undefined/implementation specific things, to not force on compilers something what will be clunky on some hardware.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a straightforward template:

```
template <class REG>
bool RegisterWrite_2(const REG &reg) {
    unsigned short regAddress = reg.address;
    unsigned short regVal = reg.value;
    // write "regVal" into address "regAddress"
    return true;
}
```

Comment: thanks Botie, and also TonyK, these answers really helps.

Answer (score 0):

Not what you were asking, but you did ask for help on making your code easier to write. So I suggest [anonymous unions and structs](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/g-fact-38-anonymous-union-and-structure/). Like this:

```
typedef struct _CHIP01_REG01
{
    union
    {
        struct
        {
            unsigned short software_reset : 1;  //bit[0]
            unsigned short reg_read_en : 1;     //bit[1]
            unsigned short add_offset : 1;      //bit[2]
            unsigned short reserved : 13;       //bit[15:3]
        };
        unsigned short value_all;
    };

    unsigned short const address = 0x00;

} CHIP01_REG01;
```

Now, instead of this:

```
chip01_regs.chip01_reg01.value.value_bit.add_offset = 1;
```

you can write this:

```
chip01_regs.chip01_reg01.add_offset = 1;
```

This feature has been available in `C` since the C11 standard, and in `C++` since the C++14 standard.

Comment: The problem with bitfields is that there's no guarantee that the compiler will arrange them in the way you had the comments. It varies from compiler to compiler, from what I understand.